# How to convert year column Y or YY to YYYY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I need to convert in SQL Server:

```
Existing YEAR col        New YEAR Col    
--------------------------------------
8                         2008
9                         2009
10                        2010
11                        2011
12                        2012
```

Comment: column + 2000?.

Comment: `col + 2000`...

Comment: this is too funny!

Comment: is it always year 2XXXX?

Comment: What does `EXISTING = 82` mean? I'm not sure there's a way to do this, actually.

Comment: Thanks Lamak Jarlh .. KeithL, I know its pretty basic..

Comment: Is there a `CENTURY` column to get a hint from?

Comment: Eric Brandt - Lamak and Jarlh solution worked for me ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want make an update:

```
    update YOUR_TABLE
    set new_year = 2000 + existing_year
```

If you want select values:

```
    select 2000 + existing_year
    from YOUR_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 2000 to each entry in the 'Existing Year Col' column